# PHP DATE created echo in HTML

Tags: php

I am trying to add the following code to echo php ECHO statement, but unsure of how.

Code to add ( to show the date in a specified format)

```
<? echo date("F j, Y", $topic->created); ?>
```

Where code should be added

```
<?php 

    $results = $page->children;

    foreach($results as $topic) { 

        //Theme each topic                   
        echo " 
            <div class='topic col-md-6'>
                <a href='{$topic->url}'><h3 class='list-group-item-heading'>{$topic->title}</h3></a>
                <strong>Started by:</strong> {$topic->createdUser->name}
                <strong>@</strong> {$topic->created} //Where code should be added.
            </div> 

            <div class='col-md text-right'>
                {$topic->numChildren}
                Comments
            </div>

            <div class='col-md text-right'>
                 20 Views
            </div>
            <hr>
        ";

    }

?>
```

Comment: One option would be to just concatenate in the string... `</strong> ".date("F j, Y", $topic->created)." //where the`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<?php 

$results = $page->children;

foreach($results as $topic) { 

    //Theme each topic                   
    echo " 
        <div class='topic col-md-6'>
            <a href='{$topic->url}'><h3 class='list-group-item-heading'>{$topic->title}</h3></a>
            <strong>Started by:</strong> {$topic->createdUser->name}
            <strong>@</strong> " . date("F j, Y", $topic->created) . " //Where code I added.
        </div> 

        <div class='col-md text-right'>
            {$topic->numChildren}
            Comments
        </div>

        <div class='col-md text-right'>
             20 Views
        </div>
        <hr>
    ";

}
```

?>

Comment: hopefully `$topic->created` is in timestamp, @Ankh2054 if this did helped you kindly accept this answer.